# Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection is not defined

Tags: oracle

Preciso de ajuda, pois não consigo prosseguir devido à mensagem

> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection is not defined.

Como posso resolver esse problema?
Estou utilizando o Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Esse erro vem de um código ou de alguma configuração de uma ide/ou programa que acessa o banco?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, o problema realmente era a configuração do DataAccess.